# How to make click option for logout

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi iam new to selenium webdriver some one help me how will make click option for below code

```html
<li id="signoutid" class="k-item k-state-default k-last" role="menuitem">
<a class="k-link" style="color: #1a1a1a;" onclick="javascript:window.open('/Account/Logout', '_self');">Logout</a>
</li>
```

I tried below Xpath its not working

.//*[@id='signoutid']/a

```
dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signoutid']/a")).click();
```

and its showing Element not visible exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
```

Comment: Please put the code in the question instead of the title, and decribe clearly what 'not working' means to you.

Comment: So, would you go to a garage and say "my car is not working"? Or do you say "My car is steering oddly, tilting to one side and it makes a wobbly sound"? Or did you have a quick check yourself and say "I have a flat tire"? The first one doesn't show much effort from your side. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a 'garage' that can fix your code for free as long as you think with us and show a little effort yourself.

Comment: please provide exception what you got..so that we can help you

Comment: its showing element not visible exception

Answer (score 0):

As per provided HTML code, i am expecting that the xpath what you used is wrong.
please try with //a[@class='k-link'][contains(text(),'Logout')]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='k-link'][contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click();
```

if still does not work, try with providing some wait and also check if this element is inside any frame or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your xpath for the web-element is wrong.
Correct xpath should be like  "//a[contains(text(),'Logout')]"

**First way**

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Logout')]").click();

**Second way**:

you can also find this element by linkText

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout"));

Now, if still the web element is not visible

Try finding out if its visible or not using

public boolean IsWebElementVisible(String xpathString){

int count = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathString")).size();

if(count>0)
   return true;

else
   return false;

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after i gave time wait below code working fine

dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signoutid']/a")).click();